# Azure Portal is showing error AADSTS50020 when I try to log in

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I am developing a desktop app with Java for a uni project and I have used Azure Active Directory to register the app. I am very new with all of this so please forgive me if I have misunderstood something. I had no problems with Azure AD until this week. When logging into the portal I am receiving the following error message:

> The portal is having issues getting an authentication token. The experience rendered may be degraded.
> Additional information from the call to get a token:
> Extension: Microsoft_AAD_IAM
> Resource: microsoft.graph
> Details: The logged in user is not authorized to fetch tokens for extension 'Microsoft_AAD_IAM' because the user account is not a member of tenant 'f8cdef31-a31e-4b4a-93e4-5f571e91255a'.
> Error details: AADSTS50020: User account '{EmailHidden}' from identity provider 'live.com' does not exist in tenant 'Microsoft Services' and cannot access the application 'c44b4083-3bb0-49c1-b47d-974e53cbdf3c'(Azure Portal) in that tenant. The account needs to be added as an external user in the tenant first.
> Sign out and sign in again with a different Azure Active Directory user account.
> Trace ID: 4b11e8b6-8400-4a15-8553-270679f41300
> Correlation ID: f0f3259b-9c04-4299-82c3-9d88a994c91c
> Timestamp: 2022-04-03 15:02:23Z

This happens every time I try to access ANYTHING on the Azure dashboard. I have tried clearing my browser's history and cookies, using a private browser, using a different browser, using a different device, using a different network and nothing has worked.

I really don't know what caused this since I am fairly convinced I didn't change anything, so I don't know why the (personal) account I have been using the whole time would now not be a part of the tenant. But since (I think) I am the admin, I have no way of accessing the 'Users' page of Azure AD and adding me back to the tenant as a user. I can't even create a new support request the Help + Support page as it just hangs - probably due to this authentication error.

Any guidance or help would be very much appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are signing in using a Live account rather than an Azure Active Directory (work or school) account.  Use your AAD account and you willwill likely sign in just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same question recently. Because you do not own an AD(tenant), so that warning message appears.

[image]